# Automatic upload of Typescript file after change to SharePoint

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, typescript, sharepoint-apps

When developing SharePoint hosted app in Visual Studio, I cannot find a way, how to tell Visual Studio in debug mode to upload typescript and their generated js files to SharePoint after changing their content.

Normally, if I change the code in javascript file (while debugging in Visual Studio), JS file is automatically uploaded to SharePoint - this is correct and expected scenario.

However, how to make it work with Typescript files? After saving Typescript file, JS file is automatically re-generated , but this JS file and TS file are not uploaded to the server.
It can be partially solved by manually changing content in JS file to trigger automatic upload to SharePoint, however I couldn't find a way to upload TS file.

Is there a way, how to tell Visual Studio to upload Typescript files (and auto-generated js files) to SharePoint in debug mode?

**Please note, that I am describing only a case in debug mode (typescript files are uploaded to sharepoint via standard packaging mechanism just fine).**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In our case we didn't want fully automatic so we used oofice pnp provisionning with a powershell script.
If you want a fully automated flow I guess gulp watch + a gulp task to do that like [gulp sp-sync](https://github.com/wictorwilen/gulp-spsync)